# How can I use phrases in query terms for the Java Youtube Search API?

Tags: java, youtube-data-api

I looking for advice how to improve my queryterm for the Youtube Search API3.
I'm searching for videos with Angelina Jordan using the Java api.

e.g.

```
YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id");
String queryterm = "Angelina Jordan";
search.setQ(queryTerm);
```

I have two problems:

1. False positives: The result contains combinations with one part of the name (e.g. Max Jordan, Angelina Jolie).
2. false negatives/missing hits: I can verify that some videos are missing in the result list.
   I split the search using the fields publishedAfter and publishedBefore to work around possible result list size limitations but that didn't help either.

Is there any way to enforce usage the two words as one String/Phrase ?

```
String queryterm = "Angelina Jordan";
String queryterm = "\"Angelina%20Jordan\"";
```

didn't work for me.

**Update:** Here's the full code of the main method from class Search in the Java sample with my changes(Download url for original sample: codeload.github.com/youtube/api-samples/zip/master).

The queryTerm "%22Angelina+Jordan%22" returns zero results for me.
For "Angelina Jordan" and "\"Angelina Jordan\"" the results looks to be the same. Including one false positive with some other Angelina: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MR1esRud-1U

I changed in the pom.xml one line to use the latest version:

<project.youtube.version>v3-rev222-1.25.0</project.youtube.version>

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// Read the developer key from the properties file.
Properties properties = new Properties();
try {
    InputStream in = Search.class.getResourceAsStream(
            "/" + PROPERTIES_FILENAME);
    properties.load(in);

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("There was an error reading " + 
            PROPERTIES_FILENAME + ": " + e.getCause()
            + " : " + e.getMessage());
    System.exit(1);
}

try {
    // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests. The last
    // argument is required, but since we don't need anything
    // initialized when the HttpRequest is initialized, we override
    // the interface and provide a no-op function.
    youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, 
            Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
        }
    }).setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-search-sample").build();

    // Prompt the user to enter a query term.
    //String queryTerm = getInputQuery();
    String queryTerm1 = "%22Angelina+Jordan%22";
    String queryTerm2 = "Angelina Jordan";
    String queryTerm3 = "\"Angelina Jordan\"";
    String queryTerm = queryTerm3;
    // Define the API request for retrieving search results.
    YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");

    // Set your developer key from the {{ Google Cloud Console }} for
    // non-authenticated requests. See:
    // {{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}
    String apiKey = properties.getProperty("youtube.apikey");
    search.setKey(apiKey);
    search.setQ(queryTerm);

    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(2014, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0);
    DateTime after = new DateTime(cal.getTime());
    cal.set(2015, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0);
    DateTime before = new DateTime(cal.getTime());
    search.setPublishedAfter(after);
    search.setPublishedBefore(before);

    // Restrict the search results to only include videos. See:
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type
    search.setType("video");

    // To increase efficiency, only retrieve the fields that the
    // application uses.
    search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title," +
            "snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
    search.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED);

    // Call the API and print results.
    SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
    List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
    System.out.println("");
    for(SearchResult result : searchResultList){
        System.out.println(result.getSnippet().getTitle());
    }

    if (searchResultList != null) {
        prettyPrint(searchResultList.iterator(), queryTerm);
    }
} catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
    System.err.println("There was a service error: " + 
            e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
            + e.getDetails().getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("There was an IO error: " + 
            e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage());
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#q), you have to *URL-escape* the search term you're passing on to the API:

> [**q**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#q) (string)
>
> The q parameter specifies the query term to search for.
>
> Your request can also use the Boolean NOT (-) and OR (|) operators to exclude videos or to find videos that are associated with one of several search terms. For example, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing", set the q parameter value to `boating|sailing`. Similarly, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing" but not "fishing", set the q parameter value to `boating|sailing -fishing.` Note that the pipe character must be URL-escaped when it is sent in your API request. The URL-escaped value for the pipe character is %7C.

That is that, instead of:

```
String queryterm = "\"Angelina%20Jordan\""
```

you have to have passed on to the API endpoint the following:

```
String queryterm = "%22Angelina+Jordan%22".
```

For this task, do use the class [`URLEncoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLEncoder.html).

You'll get then from the API an expected result:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "_NsYtSLbEVWKAMbTQaDv7p6M34k",
  "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
  "regionCode": "RO",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 372569,
    "resultsPerPage": 50
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "0ubAZtLcz-vRW-a9sCxokKKEoDE",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "otsAyDAD64Y"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-07-15T15:24:40Z",
        "channelId": "UCpeOT68U89Lly1gc8jm4GGg",
        "title": "REACTION: ANGELINA JORDAN ID RATHER GO BLIND COVER",
        "description": "ANGELINAJORDAN #ETTAJAMES #IDRATHERGOBLIND.",
        ...
        "channelTitle": "SpillingTeaWithJaybee",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2020-07-15T15:24:40Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "miSOtgMe_x6k4IhInTR8gGfIgqA",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "r6wKXJR1Eyo"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-07-15T13:55:39Z",
        "channelId": "UC0cit0oBB4aN0QVCyG7ZsIA",
        "title": "Angelina Jordan - Cant Help Falling In Love With You (Acoustic) | Reaction",
        "description": "Angelina Jordan - Cant Help Falling In Love With You (Acoustic) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBOoDXFdD70 Hope y'all enjoyed this reaction/review ...",
        ...
        "channelTitle": "Leinad",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2020-07-15T13:55:39Z"
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

For sake of completeness, here is the URL (which you may pass to `curl`) that produced the output above:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=$YOUTUBE_DATA_APP_KEY&q=%22Angelina+Jordan%22&type=video&part=id,snippet&order=date&maxResults=50`

The parameter `$YOUTUBE_DATA_APP_KEY` is your own application key (obtained from Google's developers console).

---

**Update**

The API works with `publishedAfter` and `publishedBefore` parameters too. For the following URL:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=$YOUTUBE_DATA_APP_KEY&q=%22Angelina+Jordan%22&type=video&part=id,snippet&order=date&maxResults=50&publishedAfter=2014-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&publishedBefore=2015-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z`

the API returned:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "87KRW0HHRPBRerdDi08RXAahsnc",
  "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
  "regionCode": "RO",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 73746,
    "resultsPerPage": 50
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "RQ5e0Slz0rQslnd9rTUPeXx_6xY",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "3FzeW0RoNls"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2014-12-22T05:18:09Z",
        "channelId": "UCFSx8U1zE0R40tXNV_b8XBw",
        "title": "Angelina Jordan - Summertime - George Gershwin",
        "description": "Angelina Jordan - Summertime - George Gershwin.",
        ...
        "channelTitle": "eMusic Talent",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2014-12-22T05:18:09Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "O2szi3y17VAMvWi_WSxSxp_FZ1A",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "jHqzJpEtv_8"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2014-12-22T05:05:33Z",
        "channelId": "UCFSx8U1zE0R40tXNV_b8XBw",
        "title": "Angelina Jordan - I Who Have Nothing",
        "description": "Angelina Jordan - I Who Have Nothing.",
        ...
        "channelTitle": "eMusic Talent",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2014-12-22T05:05:33Z"
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

---

### **Final update**

I confirm that *the API doesn't work as expected*! For the URL below:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=$YOUTUBE_DATA_APP_KEY&maxResults=50&part=id,snippet&publishedAfter=2014-01-01T01:00:00.125%2B01:00&publishedBefore=2015-01-01T01:00:00.125%2B01:00&q=%22Angelina+Jordan%22&type=video`

the first 6 pages produced the following output that indeed shows the `Search.list` API endpoint not working as expected:

```
001  nBGMQ9Kx9iI  Angelina Jordan - Fly Me To The Moon - The View 2014
002  ZSfgCIGd7k4  Wow! Angelina Jordan (8): "What a Difference a Day Make"
003  rI6ZhRk86Hs  Angelina Jordan (7) - Gloomy Sunday (Norways Got Talent 2014)
004  HCaDyiqs7Wg  Angelina Jordan synger Sinatra i semifinalen i Norske Talenter 2014
005  rFWs2Z_RZ3Y  Amazing seven year old sings Fly Me To The Moon (Angelina Jordan) on Senkveld "The Late Show"
006  x1_6G5VqxjQ  Angelina Jordan - I'll Be There (by Michael Jackson) on Swedish TV4 [Dec 2014]
007  zN4kAof1is0  Amazing Eight Year Old Angelina Jordan Wins Norway's Got Talent! Full Final Show
008  CtAC9LslJ_4  Let me entertain you - Åpningsnummeret i Norske Talenter-finalen 2014
009  6LIcQL5gLoY  Angelina Makes Judges Cry - I Am A Fool To Want You
010  NZU7xpeZm_c  Amazing seven year old sings Billie Holiday/I'm A Fool To Want You (Angelina Jordan)
011  5A_N1i00gFs  Angelina Jordan interview and sings Eng sub
012  LXknLZDoRVQ  Angelina Jordan - I'm A Fool To Want You - Norske Talenter - 2014
013  5HR2GP1EDr0  Angelina Jordan - Summertime - 23June 2014 - Norway
014  rzcKv9VPiAE  Angelina Jordan - Audition and backstage
015  cxD6r2Sv7SM  Angelina Jordan interview subtitled - What a Difference a Day Makes
016  xgdiUXXXft0  Angelina Jordan -- "Fly me to the moon" - subtitulado en español.
017  a7R7kVRh7Kg  Angelina Jordan - What A Wonderful World - Full song
018  5l--D51g3FY  Angelina Jordan - The Complete Gloomy Sunday Sequence - Norske Talenter
019  jHqzJpEtv_8  Angelina Jordan - I Who Have Nothing
020  24ORnvVwUmM  Amazing (Angelina Jordan) Sings What A Wonderful World In Interview Eng Sub
021  PaUyxBBL-9M  Frank Sinatra & Angelina Jordan
022  rcXuidY8AYI  Angelina Jordan Sings "Fly Me To The Moon" on Senkveld "The Late Show"
023  MR1esRud-1U  Angelina singing Hallelujah
024  Vlrbci8Xqtw  Angelina Jordan on Lilyhammer
025  sJwvSuJMcGs  Angelina Jordan - I Saw Mommy Kissing Santa Claus
026  0f39vJVXjlw  Angelina Jordan Sings Im a Fool to Want You (Acapella)
027  eQmcfIN58VM  Angelina Jordan y otras  voces maravillosas
028  443pBSpx5B4  Angelina Jordan Astar (8): "Summertime" by George Gershwin, Norske Talenter
029  IqhZPwpcXCA  Angelina Jordan - Fly me to the Moon 2014
030  3hQwtR0y2Bw  Angelina Jordan - I who have nothing
031  PmlAGdHMMrs  8 Year Old Angelina Jordan From Norway - Fly Me To The Moon
032  BBhUss-5Vr8  Gloomy Sunday   Angelina Jordan
033  m5RjEiTysI0  Angelina Jordan - "My Christmas" - official release
034  nsBfBuc9d9I  Angelina Jordan (8) sings Summertime by George Gershwin (Official HD), Norske Talenter 2014
035  KVP_rFHMHYc  Angelina Jordan - interview april 9th, 2014, english subtitles  - I (who have nothing) a capella
036  J521QFrvULI  Angelina Jordan - Fly Me To The Moon - The  View
037  ViWhR3D4QiQ  Angelina Jordan - Norske Talenter - Finale - Promo - 2014
038  jQ6EBOeSRWk  Angelina Jordan on red carpet for "Lilyhammer" By Netflix
039  3FzeW0RoNls  Angelina Jordan - Summertime - George Gershwin
040  v2C6afveJrE  Angelina Jordan (7) Norske talenter Norway's Got Talent 2014
041  fGcI3WPOKK0  Gloomy Sunday with Lyrics HD - Billie Holiday not Angelina Jordan - by arimau
042  CLBwq52aGa0  Amazing seven year old sings Fly Me To The Moon Angelina Jordan on Senkveld  The Late Show 3D720p H
043  IZxgj_W5wZc  Angelia Jordan, Magicurty, Daniel, Julie, Unique Crew, Henrik, Juice Crew, Eirik, Cato
044  49BTA7pIG1o  Angelina Jordan 7 Year Old sings Fly Me To The Moon
045  pcBoB49Gxn8  Angelina Jordan - Bang Bang - Subtitled for people outside Norway!
046  2RCTa1D1iRM  ♪ WE EQ performance (12.5K) with Angelina Jordan (8 yr.old) - Fly Me To The Moon (US TV)
047  OEjiclozx0E  Angelina Jordan - CONCERT
048  KGedseom4DY  Amazing Angelina Jordan 7 Year's Old The Winner Of Norske Talenter 2014
049  tf7KXEeMOR4  Angelina Jordan - Fly Me To The Moon - New Performance! - Norway -  2014
050  cCehijvj98E  Angelina Jordan - Norway - Lilyhammer - October 2014
051  AUV0MVTTDbY  ♫ WE EQ performance with Angelina Jordan (8 yr.old) - Fly Me to the Moon
052  sJFj0gsi1C4  Amazing 8 Year Old Angelina Jordan Sings _Shot Me Down_ Bang Bang On Norway's Got Talent[1]
053  iEKfpXD8aqM  Angelina Jordan - Complete Senkfeld Interview with Fly Me to the Moon - 2014
054  9aFkecO00yA  Angelina Jordan - Bang Bang (My Baby Shot Me Down) - Norske Talenter
055  8HlLWr5qdck  Norske Talenter 2014: Angelina Jordan 7 years sings "Summertime" by George Gershwin"  [MUST WATCH]
056  7uGS6In4hRM  Angelina Jordan Wallpaper Puzzle
057  5UxgqKZpXBQ  Angelina Jordan - Fly Me to the Moon
058  2VLPPxlhZh8  Ella Fitzgerald-Summertime-Angelina Jordan
059  OP1ZUeCrbMI  Interview with Angelina Jordan's mom - english subtitles
060  UJi6Afo_ao4  Angelina Jordan
061  2I4dSm9VC8k  Angelina Jordan - Just AMAZING
062  vJhJwF4ESuU  Angelina Jordan sings Summertime/George Gershwinon Norway's got talent(Eng sub in description HD
063  y3USd8JCsVA  I'm A Fool To Want You - Billy Holiday (Angelina Jordan) - edit m
064  RI5Rov3OOZ0  Angelina Jordan - sings 7 songs
065  mD4sXmHhvh4  Angelina Jordan - mixed clip
066  bnpFsCNKzFg  Angelina Jordan -  Complete Summertime Segment - Norske Talenter - subtitles
067  jTyziul5lD4  Bang Bang - Amazing 8 Year Old - Angelina Jordan [ LibAttitude ]
068  ZSX9HmF5jP4  Angelina Jordan ~ Norske Talenter ~ Gloomy Sunday 2014.mp4
069  2Zft92EdldM  Angelina Jordan 8 years, reincarnation of Billie Holiday   sings 7 songs
070  v0toVkiicfk  Angelina Jordan - Silent Night
071  0v5lq4HzShA  Angelina Jordan Finale opening
072  IVyjEqBHCaE  Angelina Jordan - Nobel Peace Prize Concert
073  0Bojpgkh7XI  Fly me to the moon lyric Angelina Jordan
074  84vsqzlWUUM  Amazing 7 Year Old sings Fly Me To The Moon - Angelina Jordan
075  JFBgLQV0928  New! Angelina Jordan - Norske Talenter - Teaser Clip
076  gkgBbRdVusc  Angelina Jordan (8) singing
077  KyoToltGa7w  Norske Talenter 2014 final: Angelina Jordan Astar WON! (Interview)
078  ZL37d9qHh88  Amazing Angelina Jordan Astar (8 Year Old) Sings "Bang Bang" "Shot Me Down" by Nancy Sinatra
079  9vfTFrF205c  O incrível talento dessa norueguesa de 7 anos vai te deixar boquiaberto! (Angelina Jordan)
080  -x-nAL_5GX4  Angelina Jordan Astar Norwegian singer who won the 2014 season of Norske Talenter on. The view
081  ubkx-xCuVis  Angelina jordan
082  k-SBXx-DsBc  Angelina Jordan - Bang Bang - Norske Talenter (Remix)
083  l3ij22-MB5A  Amira Willighagen - Ave Maria - Semi Finals Holland's Got Talent
084  r5GzS25fziY  Jordan astar
085  YM99-ysrivU  Angelina Jordan_TV2_Its a great honour to be a celebrity
086  jdehvxrulOo  Se koret Viva i den første semifinalen - Norske Talenter 2014
087  irUHKcc23kI  I'll be seeing you - Billie Holiday - The Notebook
088  2u40On9u1OU  UNBROKEN - Phỏng vấn Angelina Jolie
089  EjycTwdqFVM  Sandy Christen - Angelina
090  Z0htOHTOtHY  Amira Willighagen - O Mio Babbino Caro - Andre Rieu - Maastricht - July 2014
091  0SfwPb_m1Cw  SHEILA JORDAN "SHEILA'S BLUES"
092  PgG0qJC_WFw  Jordan:  Passion For Art And Home Come Together
093  jg1uYajNd78  Angelina Alexon- #MissingYou
094  n_QyUVKUVKQ  FURY: BradPitt møter Dorthe Skappel
095  -FkAs9fR63o  Stian ble sjekket opp med skjult kamera i en uke! - Hemmelig kjaerlighet - TV Lab 2014
096  7YOjZvsE3dQ  Michael Grimm- America's Got Talent Audition "You Don't Know Me"
097  clL6eXwK4_g  Angelina Cintron (Rihanna cover)
098  RyBZPgGuD_g  "Stars in Concert": Louis Armstrong / M.L. Jordan
099  jnmABALDpf4  Lady Gaga - Bang Bang (My Baby Shot Me Down) (Lyrics)
100  D6azKvvfEW8  Hans-Øivind Granerus 22 år - Norske Talenter - AUD 7033D
101  97zdn5BFXJg  Claudia Megrè in Wish you were here dei Pink Floyd
102  c4_efEebAG4  A Breathtaking Night At The Opera - Lucy Kay Sings Vissi D'arte | Britain's Got Talent
103  ttZCxDNlxZE  14 year old girl sings about bullying/Norway's Got Talent (Julie stokke)
104  VCaRuiYVG40  Ingen kjære mor. Premiere 26.august på TV 2
105  A3c3oEb5vPc  Backyard Sessions: Jordan Mitchell | Singing Songs
106  3TrSMaOZm3Y  Annie Lennox - I Put A Spell On You
107  SX-WaqK5YFA  Amira Willighagen - "Ave Maria" on Susana Giménez TV Show - Argentina - 20 August 2014
108  doSjSvvfZGw  Claudya Fritska Makes Everyone Cry by Her Voice - Audition 2 - Indonesia's Got Talent
109  4_clWepcmio  Magician Magicurty wows the judges in Norway's Got Talent
110  MXRiKEybN0s  Billie Holiday - I'll Be Seeing You
111  XTsW83FcELI  Johann Ophaug 19 år - Norske Talenter - AUD 3029D
112  D97W9xLI2Y0  Torstein shoots pool like a mad man in Norway's Got Talent!
113  VLX7_ckrA1Q  9 - لوبقدرانساكي _ جورج طحان
114  fotiA18XDPg  Corey Hart, Kim Richardson, and Jonathan Roy - "One" (live acoustic rehearsal)
115  aAuqW3rQLvg  Little World - Jordan Rabjohn // Music Video
116  usThwFmRQQU  Anabel Hernández: No puedo respirar si no hago periodismo para contar la verdad
117  PoP7_pskumc  VENUS - Young And Beautiful (Lana Del Rey cover)
118  BP1mbP227qU  Elvis Presley ♫ I've Lost You (Take ONE Series)
119  cY6fK6k2U2c  Byggmesteren Tromsø - SYSTEMHUS
120  RdZ4WPKlxHs  코니 탤벗& 조던 잰슨 DDP (Connie Talbot & Jordan Jansen)
121  C3bVycPseTw  'I'm A Fool To Want You' - Peggy Lee
122  bE3sLFRdNEE  Amazing balancing act on Ukraine's Got Talent
123  v6PdxD07wUM  Louis Amanti - Fly Me To The Moon
124  8RQpPnP1wIk  BRITAIN'S GOT TALENT 2014 AUDITIONS - JAMES SMITH
125  g-fvTCVHeI0  Anneli Drecker synger Alt Eg Såg av Sigvart Dagsland i Hver gang vi møtes.
126  ggwMGgTgTSg  Hotel California (Unplugged)
127  ztICutq2aHs  Guilherme «Magicurty" Curty tryller med popcorn og sveving i Norske Talenter
128  PXs3JF6EguQ  Boney M medley: Rasputin / Rivers of Babylon / Sunny / Daddy Cool - Allsang på Grensen 2014
129  hj1VE1RQrmM  Johnny Logan: "You Raise Me Up" TV 2 Norway: "Allsang på grensen"
130  3me3ZUWJIzs  Amira Willighagen - Behind the Scenes (Album Recording)
131  S9MgTvnNAi4  Født i feil kropp, promo høsten 2014
132  LMCCL965l0M  Nissan GT-R test TV 2
133  eBu9SbJ84Jo  Bohemian Rhapsody (Cover)
134  JD_xv14rb00  Unique Crew 19 år fra oslo - Norske Talenter - AUD 7047D
135  seszf5RWNKk  Bonnie Tyler "Total Eclipse of the Heart" m/Eirik Søfteland - Allsang på Grensen 2014
136  XZKjYJ76AWM  (PROMO) Angelina Yolima es la secre de Y Ahora Quién Duerme
137  I0VKVt5paA4  ELG synger "Sparks" av Anneli Drecker i Hver gang vi møtes 2014
138  tYMPgS6idl8  Tons of Rock 2014
139  okoDTDcOAec  Studio Rio - Billie Holiday - You've Changed
140  vMi7wi9zDR4  Henge I fingertuppene 600 meter der oppe? Noe for deg? På tur med Dag Otto
141  NI856Xkjfwo  Memorial Day Tribute
142  dpWCSPlv6Rs  Hvor farlig er gaupa? Dyrepasserne TV 2. How dangerous is the lynx?
143  sbNgy8myaKY  Lisa Ajax - Halo - Idol Sverige (TV4)
144  T9Bg55Ma6Z8  America's Got Talent S09E08 Judgment Week Kid Singing Acts Quintavious Johnson
145  51qson1SO8I  VIVA, 12 - 19 år, barne & ungdomskor under Sandnes Kulturskole, deltaker nr.7134D
146  ldPg0KTocRU  All of Me
147  xIUr9nD3H-s  Alex & Eirik, 14 & 19 år,  Poppeduo, deltaker nr. 7009, Norske Talenter 2014
148  m1YN_R9k-K4  Julie Stokke "Sweet child o' mine" av Guns N' Roses - Norske Talenter 23. mai 2014
149  IDQV95ScN0I  Boney M "Brown Girl In the Ring» - Allsang på Grensen 2014
150  SflYZOy4_J8  #askeurovision: Question for Carl Espen (Norway)
151  x626gH27sCM  Cato Alexander Eikeland rapper i finalen Norske Talenter 23. mai 2014
152  48ZLcv9nqWI  Korder: Bergdahl 'at worst a traitor'
153  wAUSWaqfc3k  Er Marianne drømmedama di?  Jakten på kjærligheten
154  MQc_ArVdkK4  Anneli Drecker synger «Alt eg såg» av Sigvart Dagsland Hver gang vi møtes 2014
155  HMjCIbNqIlQ  Meja synger All 'bout the money til en herlig allsang i Halden
156  44IKgYOa41g  Peter Bors - Norske Talenter - AUD 2052D
157  7kehg9tr0nY  Gjett retten! Tør du få servert mat med bind for øynene av Morten Ramm?
158  xBSuxSQQkFE  Fly Me to The Moon - Diana Panton
159  2C0Z8GWNvEo  Lars Lillo-Stenberg - The Invisible Man av Øivind "ELG" Elgenes - Hver gang vi møtes 2014
160  CrNEiLNmb2s  Daniel Grindeland - Norske Talenter Audition 2014
161  yBh-tY9Vutc  Fonseca - What A Wonderful World
162  RcXNcnpkWjY  Danseglad bonde søker kjærligheten -  Jakten på kjærligheten 2014
163  06vz1Bwy50U  Kenneth 11 år og Karoline 15 år - Quick change - Norske Talenter - AUD 7042D
164  8Sq6nN2Q2UU  Gloomy Sunday
165  -aDb7kqgzVs  Best International Comedy TV Series -  Lilyhammer
166  bLnnSvDlzV0  Samsaya - Tøff i pyjamas fra Hver gang vi møtes 2014
167  wWJlH406gT4  Studio Rio - Sarah Vaughan - Summertime
168  jvqlRq79I5I  Nye detaljer fra politirapporten: Northug skyldte på smørerne
169  0ogLHnwLRE4  Les oiseaux migrateurs du mois d'avril 2014
170  qoX_WBNi4PA  All Of Me - John Legend [Cover] by Julien Mueller & Julie Fournier
171  Bh3pwVyigKw  Tara Lill Flåten Nicolaisen    Big Spender    Idol Norge FULL Audition 2014
172  U9xAxYBQvuk  Farmen TV 2 høsten 2014
173  m64UeuqPQbM  Norske Talenter (Tommy Husebø) Elvis/ Norway's Got Talent
174  0oQ5C5KbWRc  BRITAIN'S GOT TALENT 2014 AUDITIONS - COLLABRO
175  qocA83Qe_eU  Carole King on 'Beautiful' on Broadway
176  7jIO-zzItKM  Rock - Raylee - Born To Be Wild
177  eP_YoBxrEVw  Tony Bennett - On the Importance of Family (excerpt from The Zen of Bennett)
178  69p2ZeZ_JkQ  Erika Albero X-Faktor Hungary (COMPLETE)
179  ESnADWT5OtU  Henrik Fuglem synge i den femte finalen i Norske Talenter 23. mai 2014
180  Bg0cvq_FKUw  Fly Me To The Moon
181  Q-n9xB1hh9s  INTERVIEW WITH Zivorad Mihajlovic Slavinski (ENGLISH subtitle)
182  TNfm4lf9CII  Brannmann og bonde, brennheit kombo!  Jakten på kjærligheten 2014
183  81gsMv05m4E  Dianne Reeves - Summertime - 7/6/1994 - Blue Room (Official)
184  7tFK2owMfdk  Tony Bennett - I'm a Pacifist (excerpt from The Zen of Bennett)
185  Fa2K1XC6auw  Rebecka | Talang Sverige
186  IRt-LtLMgKs  Gloomy Sunday
187  WMe2wGfjFRk  Diana Kalashova - I will always love you "Lidushik live concert in Armenia"
188  Y8m2xGofg4c  Lila Elveseter Abrahamsen - 11 years old - Give Your Heart A Break
189  6iiIoDI5ocE  Viva Sandnes Kulturskolekor opptrer i den femte finalen i Norske Talenter
190  m7Q5f0vVMUg  What a Diff'rence a Day Made
191  v4dIgQGNUBM  Idol-Medley med Alejandro Fuentes, Alexander With og Sandra Lyng fra Allsang på grensen
192  w7yz_GQWPm4  Forever Gentlemen vol.2 - Misty [Sofia Essaïdi & Roch Voisine] (extrait coulisses)
193  XLVDgahWJcw  Konsert med Rock & Kor og KORK
194  UxT9zEGpRkg  Hansine besøker moren sin | Tangerudbakken | Dplay Norge
195  DYybRriXI0c  Alexander Rybak - Smooth Escape av D`Sound og Simone i Hver gang vi møtes 2014
196  jaZYv69brh8  Eirik Sætre Hove opptrer med jo-jo i den femte finalen i Norske Talenter 23. mai 2014
197  Kxan0bOG9qA  TV Record mostra a formação de um piloto da Força Aérea - Episódio II
198  oV6yKJetY1c  Alfa Romeo 4C TEST, handmade head turner - Broom TV 2
199  jo6mrVEVWdg  Maria Arredondo og Torstein Sødal synger "A whole new world" fra Aladdin filmen - Allsang på grensen
200  vJPJ19ix2ic  Norske Talenter Ine Synger Bob Dylan/Make You Feel My Love
201  qU1SblEZ2sA  P!nk supports Youth Off The Streets
202  HvAeIwZvgxg  Dina Matheussen 10 år - Norske Talenter - AUD 7023D
203  -jTsZpOteVQ  Flugschreiber der vermissten Boeing: Warum er so schwer zu finden ist
204  CZHxr05EGJ0  Yo Soy: Amy Winehouse fascinó al público con la canción 'Rehab'
205  aMk9XTGtnKg  Strings of Soul | Talang Sverige
206  mBpRr0ODG9k  Go For Goal - Thursday 3rd July 2014
207  nThLeRV69JY  fly me to the moon
208  BSb1k9PhEPA  English kjeringråd from Gufrid
209  Nv3XipXneAY  PAULA TOLLER - fly me to the moon
210  gLc9pyYcpH4  RickK - Fly Me To The Moon ( live)
211  _HUdcsR8DBA  Balloons - Andrew Cole & Glenn Morrison at Mississauga Celebration Square
212  QGERsD8utFQ  Connie Francis - IIevame a la Luna {Fly Me To The Moon}  (Spanish version) (9)
213  1SRGr65wstM  Ingvar Olsen    Blue Darling    Idol Norge FULL Audition 2014
214  sDCdGl58-MY  Summertime ♡ - Cover
215  f9_s5Mqn1h8  Enfald eller mångfald i läroboken? - Om livsåskådningar i skolan
216  CBsQWV7zyLc  Dungeon Defenders Eternity: Content Update 2 Preview
217  qIEmp96i2DU  Medi - One Is Not Enough - Live in Paris
218  aqrNr_OtBvo  TOM: NZRTH
219  jIzxL3lvLa4  Fly Me To The Moon
220  zhZMtir1_JE  MY FIRST SINGING VIDEO! Somewhere Only We Know By Keane Cover by Orly Alexandra
221  1u0-x_siyck  Remerciement Raphaël (styledotboy.com) et bienvenue !
222  QNHMOjBX2FY  Пуск РКН Союз-2.1б с КА Ресурс-П № 2
223  WMW5ZOs7Vf4  Reporter Line på MGP-Finalen
224  zUfSYd6y5es  Unik 4 (MGP-junior vinnerne) med låta "Så sur da" i Allsang på grensen
225  FjyuquwhxkI  Amira Willighagen - "O Mio Babbino Caro" Rehearsal - Concert Durban, South Africa - 9 August 2014
226  o91t8hUyvNY  PELLEK - FLY ME TO THE MOON (Unplugged)
227  849BXOrYioE  Dolan Car Crash
228  76_R9WpubFQ  Mathias Bonde: Jeg kommer til at savne AGF
229  5F3rwjoRYEk  Billie Holiday - I'll Never Be The Same (1937)
230  PrOPHSeSlWw  Tony Bennett - Fly Me To The Moon (In Other Words) - 9/6/1991 - Prince Edward Theatre (Official)
231  vQklQ1lVjDg  BU Today Sessions: BU Scarlet Jazz Combo - "All of Me"
232  KURwlIJ-Zm0  Kvammen, Kristensen & Rake - Something [Official music video HD]
233  QMvQ543mCOY  Hermitcraft Iron Overflow
234  KSecN1RIvmI  Tara Tiba-Fly me to the moon- تارا تیبا - با من بیا به آسمون
235  oe0aAzOn360  Swing Republic - You Let Me Down (ft. jazz legend Billie Holiday) - (Lyrics Video)
236  yy_WbILmiGY  Fly Me To The Moon "Risa Jazz Covers"
237  Nh30YVzIMXw  Idol Jr Norge 2014 Kyle Alessandro audition
238  nvuwbQWewBY  Celine Dion / What A Wonderful World
239  lIrTLdnQnns  Winning Moment - Putri Ariani - The Winner - RESULT SHOW - Indonesia's Got Talent
240  iNWMEsFiA28  CATO 2014 Holiday TV Behind the Scenes Video
241  XGTnYQ-V5z0  VG-lista til Sandnessjøen
242  cUIGstwhi_M  2014: Our Year in Splendor and in Sunshine (The Curtis Video Holiday Card)
243  GWsUlT6EefE  Beskjæring av bærbusker
244  vQh0shj_Nqo  Old time Rock´n Roll - Music video - Baily with Gina Michaells
245  Irw1El-xxbM  The Bluebeaters - I Saw Mommy Kissing Santa Claus
246  BOLl_ajoxRc  DVINES & ALMOST FAMOUS Band - At Last (Etta James cover. LIVE)
247  b5lK4iiJM_o  Emi Sunshine "Folsom Prison Blues"
248  cpT27Z1nF5E  I'm fool to want you Cheryl Bentyne
249  cBGQLSv6h9E  Uke 45 - Nora kjører MASARATI
250  MHLc_EwjNC0  Aram Mp3 Singing With His Mom - Fly Me To The Moon (Live Concert) 09
251  UMzsOGrIXx4  Wild horse - Gina Michaells (great original country rock)
252  Y3nY8Pj_RkY  2014 12 12 NIETYKALNI 19
253  0MWRheQtvmA  Billie Holiday - Don't Explain (Live 1958)
254  Uzeg7QDoPC4  Lucía García de 11 años canta Ave Maria ( Shubert)
255  EiNKgHWmeeg  Wszyscy atakuja Korwin-Mikkego
256  dsFecWxewWs  Taller de Reebok core training
257  xKy6gF8n1qw  Sisi - The Sun
258  NcBxXRVhV_o  Billie Holiday - All Of Me (1941)
259  Qbd0ySmIt_U  Fresno State Thursday - Steve Sarkisian Presser
260  Wb_0U71efEY  ბოშათა ჟამი. როგორ ცხოვრობს საქართველოში ყველაზე მარგინალიზებული ეთნიკური ჯგუფი (პანორამა)
261  33eMPu-Knr0  Toby Randall - Born To Die - Lana Del Rey
262  86yTC8l7zSc  The Backstreet Boys - I Want It That Way [acoustic cover]
263  1838lqvadWY  Secret Love official music video Dannielle Gaha
264  2dnMmCFuXJA  En mayo celebramos con las madres [Somos Emocionantes] Telemedellín
265  c_8UyDt6mB4  Nils om Skeez TV Battles live 6/4
266  WCdMIQoTzWc  Shirley Bassey - Ev'ry Time We Say Goodbye
267  Rcv58bq81M4  Tavaszi barack smink, barack ruhához
268  iWhapM8gKQQ  ZOE D. - WELCOME TO MY WORLD
269  FoJNpd6GRVo  Magos Herrera – Raising her voice for women’s rights
270  gQNJuNbZIrE  David Guetta - Shot Me Down ft. Skylar Grey
271  Plm0-RV5IOU  Ariana Savalas - "Fly me to the Moon" (Live)
272  hb6iH5su040  This girl has an amazing voice! Jerain plays brand new song, Begging For More, unplugged
273  G7YWZWW7goA  Etta James - At Last
274  WEkKUFey-JE  Páll Óskar rífur gítarleikara úr sambandi í Hljómahöll
275  ld0CHySMc1s  Erlend Ropstad - Maria (Full HD)
276  6vxWm5OZ-84  Summertime (Cover) - Guthrie Brown
277  scaZk7oaZHY  Grand Blanc @ Printemps de Bourges "L'Homme Serpent" LIVE
278  BxBSPBu1lPY  Laat het Los (Let it go, Frozen) Sterre Live (10 years)
279  FFNqTStUDYk  Dinah Washington- What A Difference A Day Makes (1959)
280  oyZgHXEbm-M  BLUE SOL #Camaléo (Live Festival Oil And Sand)
281  n-0QxtdcV40  FREDDI SMASHES 2x220kg/485lbs
282  ca_a7m3mJLc  600. VÝROČIE PRVEJ ZMIENKY O OBCI PROCHOT
283  uCRua-sS2ZU  Kerssangdiens 2014 - Silent Night
284  r6PetmaZzvw  PUGSLEY BUZZARD - JAZZ
285  qWQwrvay0Ns  02 - IMA - You'll Never Find Another Love Like Mine
286  A8eLHZXv-60  Billie Holiday - Summertime
287  Isqa8IkpfSw  Say Something - Norwegian Cover
288  oVDCObdXlAQ  Vake2014 - Team Sweden
289  _GzBq97X2DE  #eusoucers
290  0ExN5VZAhB8  Fly Me To The Moon - Jana Ann Cover
291  2sfpB1M_Kq4  The Dietrichs - Bang Bang (Nancy Sinatra)
292  XCHXhfzxo3c  All Of Me - John Legend (A Cappella Cover) - Colleen Dauncey & Kholby Wardell
293  1tMV2_H1ZPs  Fly Me To The Moon - Frank Sinatra (Cover) by Louis Amanti
294  7ot1BCxME80  January Favourites 2014! | Rachael Jade
295  49ixVrOF8Aw  Adieu au langage (Goodbye to Language) - Jean-Luc Godard (trailer with English subtitles)
296  jACb9ErTr-U  เรื่องเล่าเช้านี้ สุดตราตรึง หนูน้อยนอร์เวย์ 7 ขวบ ร้องเพลง gloomy sunday กระตุกอารมณ์ผู้ฟัง
297  P1N0OfMx_OU  Noah Buccolini sorprendió con su voz angelical - SÚPER ESTRELLAS
298  pYT-wjO21IA  Spectacular Salsa   Paddy&Nico Subtitulado
299  -Rh4cPX4oT4  Laura Michelle | I Saw Mommy Kissing Santa Claus
300  LSHsLATHWqQ  Akiko - Fly Me To The Moon
```

Look only at entries following the line numbered `101`.

For sake of completeness, the table above was verbatim generated by the following command:

```
  $ cat search-result[0-5].json|
    json -Jusm|
    sed -nr 's|^.*/(videoId\|title)=||p'|
    sed -r 'N;s/\n/  /'|
    html-cref|
    nl -w3 -s '  ' -n rz|
    sed -r 's/^/    /'
```

at a stock GNU/Linux `bash` prompt using the common GNU/Linux power-tools `sed` and `nl`; also using the free software tools [Json-Type](http://www.nongnu.org/json-type/) for `json`, and [Html-Cref](https://github.com/stvar/html-cref/) for `html-cref`.

The files `search-result[0-5].json` were obtained via API result set pagination using the URL shown above.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218010/discussion-on-answer-by-stvar-how-can-i-use-phrases-in-query-terms-for-the-java).